# Fire Third party tag on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fire a third party tag on button click. I am doing it through one of the Tag Manager (DTM). My button id is `btnFindStores` and I have put this ID in element tag field in DTM. I have done it via JQuery. My code is

```
jQuery.get("http://20762607p.rfihub.com/ca.gif?rb=2379&ca=20762607&_o=2379&_t=20762607&rd=order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx#pg1");
```

Can anyone please help me out as it is not getting fired when I click on that button.

Comment: The first step is to look at the error console. You will likely see an error message there.

Comment: I am getting this error...

jquery-1.9.1.min.js:19 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx?pid=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://20762607p.rfihub.com/ca.gif?rb=2379&ca=20762607&_o=2379&_t=20762607&rd=order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.